# @property for Core Foundation variable

Tags: iphone

In my program I am setting up core foundation variables using automatic reference counting.  For my @interface I use:

@property (nonatomic, assign) CGRect home;

In my @implementation I use:

@synthesize home;

I am getting an error "Type of property 'home" ('struct CGRect') does not match type of ivar 'home' ('struct CGRect *).  Please advise so I can keep my getters and setters for the CGRect variable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you declare an ivar named home, aside from the @property declaration? If so, include that line of code in the question.

Comment: CGRect is not CoreFoundation, it's Core Graphics. Just saying...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your interface you must have something like this:

```
@interface MyClass: NSObject {
    CGRect *home;
//         ^ here's your problem
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGRect home;
@end
```

Delete the asterisk from `CGRect *home`.